# WiFi on Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino

Dummy question I was unable to find out: the shields that I use to add WiFi (802.11b/g/n) to a Raspberry Pi, could also be used on a Nano?

In other words: how easy/feasible is to add WiFi to a Arduino Nano board?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are multiple WiFi shields for Arduino, but one of the issues will be size if you want to use a Nano board. There are a few modules out there but they operate on 3.3V logic, not 5V which is what the Nano supplies.

I suggest trying an [Arduino Pro Mini 3.3V/8MHz](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini). Please note that:

1. There are two versions of the Pro Mini: 5V/16MHz and 3.3V/8MHz (you'll want the 3.3V)
2. an FTDI TTL-232R-3V3 Cable so you can program the board.

In terms of getting WiFi, the [ESP8266](https://github.com/esp8266/esp8266-wiki/wiki) is getting a lot of attention lately. It's pretty cheap and supports 802.11 b/g/n protocols.

There are tutorials out there on using the [ESP8266 with the Arduino Pro Mini](http://www.instructables.com/id/ESP8266-Wifi-Temperature-Logger/?ALLSTEPS) and Razvan Dubau wrote a nice guide on using this module with [Raspberry PI](http://www.extragsm.com/blog/2014/12/03/connect-esp8266-to-raspberry-pi/)

If you really must use the Nano board, you could use a [level shifter](http://www.adafruit.com/product/735) to go from 3.3V logic to 5V.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips George!

Comment: No worries, feel free to vote and mark it if it was useful ;) Thanks!

Comment: I certainly will do so as soon as I reach 15 reputation as the site doesn't allow me to vote before that ;-) Again, thanks!

Comment: What about this one?
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield
will this work with the nano?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou As you can see on the [nano's specs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardNano#techspecs), it operates at 5V as the ArduinoWiFiShield, however, notice the form factor of the shield. It's the form factor for an Arduino Uno, so if you want to use your nano with this shield, you'd need a breakout board for the Nano with Uno's Shield dimensions and female header pins, defeating the purpose of Nano's small form factor: probably simpler to use an Arduino Uno if you want to use the ArduinoWiFiShield. If you want to use an ESP with a Nano you can, but you'll need a level shifter..

Comment: ...once you test on a breadboard you can design a minimal form factor nano shield for the ESP. check [this out](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardNano#techspecs)