# UNO can't communicate with ESP-01 module

Tags: arduino

I have an `ESP-01` module connected to the arduino and powered by an external power source. I tried sending AT commands using the serial monitor in Arduino IDE, blue led blinks each time I send a command, but I get no response back.

```
ESP    → Power
Vcc    → 3.3v
GND    → GND

ESP    → Arduino UNO
GND    → GND
CH_PD  → 3.3v (tied 10kOhm)
RX     → RX (connected 10kOhm to GND and RX Arduino)
TX     → TX
```

I tried swapping the `TX` and `RX` pins, directly connecting the pins without resistors, or even connecting the other pins to either `3.3v` or `GND` like other tutorials schematics. I also tried uploading the BareMinimum code or SoftSerial samples provided by other tutorials. In the end, nothing works.

Also when I try to upload code to the `ESP-01` through the IDE I get

```
"warning: espcomm_sync failed error: espcomm_open failed" errors.
```

Is my module fried or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are powering the ESP module at 3.3V, but Arduino's logic is at 5V. You will need  a level shifter if you plan to use your ESP module with an Arduino Uno. There's a smaller Arduino Pro Mini running at 8MHz and 3.3V you could use though. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496931/wifi-on-arduino-nano/28498412#28498412)